# can you charge samsung tablet with samsung phone charger

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Someone told me that you shouldn't charge your tablet with your phone charger,it will ruin it. Is this true?  They're both Samsung.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine, just slower (depending on the rating of the two chargers).

It's possible for the tablet to draw more power than can be provided by a weaker charger, so for it to charge well you should ideally have it powered off or at least idle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and it's normal to understand that it's not a original charger for your device.

So it must be take extra time for charging.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can charge but you will face some problem like slow charging , less battery backup, and also other battery related problem in future or heating of device

Comment: What is "battery backup" and why would *less* current increase heat issues?